# NameError: name '_color_name' is not defined

Tags: python

I know this topic comes up a lot, however I am having a hard time applying what I have read to my specific situation. I am taking a very beginner course in Python, with no plans on actually becoming a programmer because, frankly I suck at this. Please be gentle?
My Error:

NameError: name '_color_name' is not defined

My Code:

```
class Project:
    _number_of_colors = 0
    _colors = [None for x in range(MAX_BEAD_COLORS)]
    _total_beads = 0
    _total_beads_metallic = 0

    def get_colors(self):
        done = False
        color = None
        has_metallic_beads = False

        while not done:
            has_metallic_beads = y_or_n("Is the color metallic (Y/N)? ")
            if(has_metallic_beads):
                color = MetallicColor()
            else:
                color = Color()
            color.input()
            self._colors[self._number_of_colors] = color
            self._number_of_colors = self._number_of_colors + 1
            done = y_or_n("Are there more colors in your project (Y/N)? ")

    def display(self):
        counter = 0
        percent_metallic = 0.0
        percent_color = 0.0
        color = None

        while counter < self._number_of_colors:
            color = self._colors[counter]
            percent_color = 100 * color.get_total_beads() / _total_beads
            print("Color", (counter + 1), "-", percent_color, "of total:", color.get_total_beads(), "beads of", color.get_color(), ".")
            counter = counter + 1
        percent_metallic = 100 * self._total_beads_metallic / self._total_beads
        print("Total Beads in Project:", _total_beads)
        print("Total Metallic Beads in Project:", _total_beads_metallic)
        print("Total percentage of Metallic Beads:", "{:.2f}".format(percent_metallic_beads))

    def calculate(self):
        counter = 0
        ingredient = None

        while counter < self._number_of_ingredients:
            ingredient = self._ingredients[counter]
            self._total_beads = self._total_beads + color.get_qty_beads()
            self._total_beads_metallic = self._total_beads_metallic + color.get_total_beads_metallic()
            counter = counter + 1

class Color:
    _color_name = ""
    _qty_beads = 0

    def input(self):
        self._color_name = get_string("What is the name of the color? ")
        self._qty_beads = get_real("How many " + _color_name + " does your project require? ")

    def get_color_name(self):
        return self._color_name

    def get_qty_beads(self):
        return self._qty_beads

class MetallicColor(Color):
    def input(self):
        self._color_name = get_string("What is the name of the color? ")
        self._qty_beads = get_real("How many " + _color_name + " does your     project require? ")


def project():
    project = None

    project = Project()
    project.get_colors()
    project.calculate()
    project.display()
project()
```

I have removed some validation and prompt code to reduce the post size.

Comment: You should include the entire traceback. It has useful things like the line number. That said, your issue is hat you're not using `self._color_name`.

Comment: You should also include *all* the relevant code, there are many things that are not defined in the code that you posted, such as `get_string`, `y_or_n`, `MAX_BEAD_COLORS`...

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I thought too much code would be an irritation. I will include all of it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

```
class MetallicColor(Color):
    def input(self):
        self._color_name = get_string("What is the name of the color? ")
        self._qty_beads = get_real("How many " + _color_name + " does your     project require? ")
```

"how many " + **self.**_color_name

Comment: oh my gosh. thank you!! and I am embarrassed because that has looked weird to me the whole time, but I couldn't figure out why. I need to stick to web design, ha!
Now on to the next error! Thanks again!